# what is echart type in typescript Vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, echarts

I am using Vu3 typescript. I wanted to inject echarts into the component. but typescript keeps asking me what is a type of echarts that i injected. that is why I used any type as a solution. but I think It is not a good way. can u guys tell me what is type of echarts.

plugin file (where echarts was provided):

```
import * as echarts from "echarts";
import { App } from "vue";

export default {
  install: (app: App) => {
    app.provide("echarts", echarts);
  },
};
```

component file:

```
<template>
  <div ref="theChart" :style="{ height: '500px' }"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, inject } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "login",
  components: {},
  setup() {
    const echarts: any = inject("echarts");
    return {
      echarts,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.drawChart();
  },
  methods: {
    drawChart() {
      //Initialize the echarts instance based on the prepared dom
      let myChart = this.echarts.init(this.$refs.theChart,  null, { renderer: 'svg' });
      //Specify configuration items and data for the chart
      let option = {
        title: {
          text: "ECharts Introductory example",
        },
        tooltip: {},
        legend: {
          data: ["Sales volume"],
        },
        xAxis: {
          data: [
            "shirt",
            "Cardigan",
            "Chiffon shirt",
            "trousers",
            "High-heeled shoes",
            "Socks",
          ],
        },
        yAxis: {},
        series: [
          {
            name: "Sales volume",
            type: "bar",
            data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
          },
        ],
      };
      //Use the configuration items and data just specified to display the chart.
      myChart.setOption(option, true);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

when I write

```
const echarts = inject("echarts");
```

it shows error
TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown' for the following code

```
let myChart = this.echarts.init(this.$refs.theChart,  null, { renderer: 'svg' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways to resolve，You can choose a way that is convenient for you

1、if you are using npm, the default ts type of echarts is in a separate npm package, you can try to introduce it instead of any

```
npm install --save-dev @types/echarts
```

2、you can define a .d.ts file, define the types yourself

```
declare module "echarts" {
  //the function or properties you may need to use
}
```

you use a provide,inject, but it doesn't make any sense, you can import echarts when you need

```
//@types/echarts does not need to import
import echarts from 'echarts'
app.provide('echarts',echarts);
//you use inject
const echarts = inject<typeof echarts>('echarts');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. if I use the first way, how can I import the type of echart?

Comment: you just need to import the package, the IDE will auto distinguish it

Comment: import { defineComponent, inject } from "vue";
import "@types/echarts";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "login",
  components: {},
  setup() {
    const echartsModule: echarts = inject("echarts");
    return {
      echartsModule,
    };
  }
It shows me TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'echarts' as a type.
i still don't know where is mistake ...thanks for answering

Comment: you should read how to use typescript, i had a modify on the answer

Comment: I know, it is my first time use typescript. i am kind of overwhelming